# swapcontext failing in many-to-many thread implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am tasked with implementing a many-to-many thread manager in C++. I've got most of it more or less down, but I'm having serious problems with `swapcontext` in my `uthread_yield()` method. Here's the code

```
/*
 * uthread.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 12, 2016
 *      Author: michael
 */

#include "uthread.h"
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#ifndef STDIO_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

namespace std {
/*
 * Initializes all the variables and allocates memory when needed
 */

int uthread::maxThreads;
int uthread::currentThreads;
pthread_mutex_t uthread::mapMutex;
pthread_mutex_t uthread::qMutex;
pthread_mutex_t uthread::threadMutex;
map<int,UserThread*>* uthread::threadMap;
priority_queue<UserThread*>* uthread::threadQueue;

void uthread::uthread_init(int numKernelThreads) {

    pthread_mutex_t tester;
    pthread_mutex_init(&tester,NULL);
    uthread::maxThreads=numKernelThreads;
    uthread::currentThreads=0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&threadMutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&qMutex,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mapMutex,NULL);
    threadQueue= new priority_queue<UserThread*>;
    threadMap=new map<int,UserThread*>;
}
int uthread::uthread_create(void (* func)( )) {
    //Create ucontext to be used in in
    ucontext_t* ucp=(ucontext_t*)malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));
    getcontext(ucp);
    ucp->uc_stack.ss_sp=(void*)malloc(16384);
    ucp->uc_stack.ss_size=16384;
    makecontext(ucp, func, 0); //make the context for a thread running func
    //Create UserThread
    time_t currTime;
    time(&currTime);
    UserThread* newThread=new UserThread(ucp,currTime);
    //Thread Creation Logic
    pthread_mutex_lock(&threadMutex);
    if (currentThreads>=maxThreads) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&qMutex);
        threadQueue->push(newThread);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);
        return 0;
    }
    else {

        int (*execute)(void *)= (int (*)(void *)) func;
        int tid=clone(execute,ucp->uc_stack.ss_sp,CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES,NULL);
        if (tid==-1) { //clone failed
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);
            return -1;
        }
        currentThreads++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);
        /*
         * Map tid -> UserThread in thread map
         */

        threadMap->insert(pair<int,UserThread*>(tid,newThread));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
void uthread::uthread_exit() {
    /*
     * Get the corresponding UserThread object from the map
     */
    printf("Start Exit \n");
    int threadID=syscall(SYS_gettid) ;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
    if (threadMap->find(threadID)==threadMap->end()) { //Cannot find map;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&threadMutex);
        currentThreads--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Getting Curr Thread\n");
    UserThread* currThread= threadMap->at(threadID);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qMutex);

    if (threadQueue->empty()) { //No items on queue, delete memory references and exit
        printf("Queue is Empty");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
        threadMap->erase(threadID);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&threadMutex);
        currentThreads--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);
        delete currThread;
        exit(0);
    }
    else { //Remove and delete memory reference to old thread, set context to new thread
        printf("Swapping Queue\n");
        UserThread* newThread=threadQueue->top();
        threadQueue->pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
        threadMap->insert(pair<int,UserThread*>(threadID,newThread)); //Update Map
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
        printf("Deleting Current Thread\n");
        delete currThread;
        printf("Setting Context\n");
        setcontext(newThread->ucp);
        printf("set context failed\n");
    }
}
void uthread::uthread_yield() {
    printf("Start Yield \n");
    int threadID=syscall(SYS_gettid) ;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
    UserThread* currThread= threadMap->at(threadID);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qMutex);
    if (threadQueue->empty()) {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("Queue Not Empty\n");
        currThread->updateRuntime(time(NULL)); //updates run time account for time it's been on thread
        UserThread* highestPriority=threadQueue->top();
        if (highestPriority->getRunTime()>currThread->getRunTime()) { //highestPriority is lower priority than currently running thread
            printf("lowest runtime is running\n");

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);
            return;
        }
        else {
            printf("SwapContext\n");
            threadQueue->pop();
            threadQueue->push(currThread);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
            threadMap->insert(pair<int,UserThread*>(threadID,highestPriority)); //Update Map reference
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
            //Swaps contexts
            swapcontext(currThread->ucp,highestPriority->ucp);
            printf("Swapcontext Failed\n");
        }

    }

}
int uthread::startThread(void* arg ) {
    printf("Thread Cloned\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
    int threadID=syscall(SYS_gettid) ;
    UserThread* currThread= threadMap->at(threadID);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);
    setcontext(currThread->ucp);
    return 0;

}
}
```

And this is the code of my corresponding UserThread object:

```
    /*
 * UserThread.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 12, 2016
 *      Author: michael
 */

#include "UserThread.h"
/*
 * Constructor. UCP is taken in as well as start time
 * Run time initialized to 0
 *
 */
UserThread::UserThread(ucontext_t *ucp,time_t st) {
    this->ucp=ucp;
    this->startTime=(time_t*)malloc(sizeof(time_t));
    this->runTime=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    *startTime=st;
    *runTime=0;

}
/**
 * Deconstructor
 */
UserThread::~UserThread() {
    //free(ucp->uc_stack.ss_sp);
    //free(ucp);
    free(startTime);
    free(runTime);

}
/*
 * adds the running time in seconds (as a double) to the current running time. Also updates the start time
 */
void UserThread::updateRuntime(time_t currTime) {
    double diffTime=difftime(currTime,*startTime);
    *runTime=*runTime+diffTime;
    *startTime=currTime;
}
/*
 * Just Updates the start time
 */
void UserThread::updateStartTime(time_t newTime) {
    *startTime=newTime;
}
/*
 * getter
 */
double UserThread::getRunTime() {
    double rTime=*runTime;
    return rTime;
}
/*
 * getter
 */
time_t UserThread::getStartTime() {
    return *startTime;
}
/*
 * THIS IS REVERSED ON PURPOSE. C++ runs a maximum priority queue by default
 * by overloading the < operator backwards, that isn't an issue. Sketchy? Yes
 * Also functional
 */
bool UserThread::operator <(UserThread* t2) {
    return this->getRunTime() > t2->getRunTime();
}
```

`uthread_yield()` will correctly work once for each thread, then fail. Any idea why this is? I've stared at this code for hours and at this point I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? And **C Is not the same as C++**

Comment: Yes. It doesn't let me step into the swapcontext method. I know C isn't the same as C++, but I am using a C library in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually failing: it's just printing your failure message.  Your yield implementation finishes with:

```
swapcontext(currThread->ucp, highestPriority->ucp);
printf("Swapcontext Failed\n");
```

So the yielding thread swaps away after `swapcontext()`, which is fine - but when that thread is later swapped back to, it will return from `swapcontext()` and unconditionally execute the printf().  You need:

```
if (swapcontext(currThread->ucp, highestPriority->ucp) == -1) {
    printf("Swapcontext Failed\n");
    /* You need to fix up your queue and map here to account for the
     * failure to context switch, and then probably loop back and look
     * for another candidate thread to swap to. */
}
```

I also noticed that your `uthread_create()` function accesses the map and unlocks `mapMutex` without locking the mutex first.

You're mixing pthreads functions with the bare `clone()` syscall, which is unsupported.  Use `pthread_create()` / `pthread_exit()` for managing the underlying threads.  One way to do this is by having thread created by `pthread_create()` start at a scheduling function that pulls the thread to run from your queue:

```
void* uthread::newThread(void* arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&qMutex);

    if (threadQueue->empty()) {
        printf("No thread to start.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    UserThread* highestPriority = threadQueue->top();
    threadQueue->pop();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);

    int threadID = syscall(SYS_gettid);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMutex);
    threadMap->insert(pair<int,UserThread*>(threadID,highestPriority)); //Update Map reference
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMutex);

    setcontext(highestPriority->ucp);
    printf("setcontext() Failed\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

...then you can simplify `uthread_create()` by *always* pushing the new user thread onto the queue, and only conditionally creating the underlying thread:

```
// ... start of uthread_create() up to creating new UserThread ...

pthread_mutex_lock(&qMutex);
threadQueue->push(newThread);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&qMutex);

//Thread Creation Logic
pthread_mutex_lock(&threadMutex);
if (currentThreads < maxThreads) {
    pthread_t new_pthread;
    if (pthread_create(*new_pthread, NULL, uthread::newThread, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("New pthread creation failed.\n");
    } else {
        currentThreads++;
    }        
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&threadMutex);

return 0;
```

By the way, it seems that you're using the `threadMap` just as a way to implement thread-local-storage: you could instead use the built-in pthreads thread-local-storage API (`pthread_key_create()` / `pthread_setspecific()` / `pthread_getspecific()`).